# Select Angular UI tab by url parameter

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI tabs and would like to achieve two things
First, the url should update when a tab is selected (bookmarkable).
Second, I would like the correct tab to load based on the url.

Eg. http://foobar.com/foo/tab1 should select tab1

Thanks

Comment: Please, more details about the question.

Comment: Are "Angular UI tabs" the same as jQuery tabs? If so, plenty of existing answers await on SO.

Comment: Did you obtain any solution? I am also facing a similar problem. In my case I have got route parameters. So for example `https:../tab/1` should automatically select Tab1.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:
[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q7ZyOhKQbtdf53GMJYMC?p=preview)

$routeProvider:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider
    .when('/:id', {
      controller: 'TabsDemoCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'tab.html'
    });
});
```

I check for routeParams in controller.